# Pine script code - How fix Syntax error at input '=' issue

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am having problems with this part of my code `temp_x[j] = data[i - window_size + j]`, the console says that: Error en 16:0 Syntax error at input '='

I tried to solve it on my own by replacing with the code mentioned below but it keeps giving errors, what could be a possible solution to this problem?

How could I fix it?

full code pine script:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Trend Prediction", shorttitle="Trend Prediction", overlay=true)

// Input variables
window_size = input(title="Window Size", type=input.integer, defval=10)
train_size = input(title="Train Size", type=input.integer, defval=70)
test_size = input(title="Test Size", type=input.integer, defval=30)

// Load data
data = close
x = array.new_float(0)
y = array.new_int(0)
for i = window_size to bar_index
    temp_x = array.new_float(window_size)
    for j = 0 to window_size - 1
        temp_x[j] = data[i - window_size + j]
    x := array.push(x, temp_x[0], temp_x[1], temp_x[2], temp_x[3], temp_x[4], temp_x[5], temp_x[6], temp_x[7], temp_x[8], temp_x[9])
    y := array.push(y, data[i] > data[i - 1] ? 1 : 0)

// Split into train and test sets
split_index = round(array.size(x) * train_size / 100)
x_train = array.slice(x, 0, split_index)
y_train = array.slice(y, 0, split_index)
x_test = array.slice(x, split_index + 1, array.size(x))
y_test = array.slice(y, split_index + 1, array.size(y))

// Train decision tree model
model = ml_decision_tree(x_train, y_train, max_depth=3)

// Predict trend
predictions = ml_predict(model, x_test)
trend = array.new_bool(0)
for i = 0 to array.size(predictions) - 1
    trend := array.push(trend, predictions[i] == 1)

// Plot trend
plot(trend ? data[split_index + 1] : na, color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=3, title="Bullish Trend")
plot(not trend ? data[split_index + 1] : na, color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=3, title="Bearish Trend")
```

i try replacing with:
temp_x[j] = data[i - window_size + j]

but still causing problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pinescript, you can't address array like in python.
To retrieve a value, you must use :

```
MyValue = array.get(NameOfMyArray, IndexOfTheValueInTheArray)
```

To record a value, you must use :

```
array.set(NameOfMyArray, IndexOfTheValueInTheArray, Myvalue)
```

So you must change :

```
temp_x[j] = data[i - window_size + j]
```

To

```
array.set(temp_x, j, data[i - window_size + j])
```

Comment: I got some more errors:

11:28:30 Error at 17:0 Cannot call 'operator SQBR' with 'expr1'=array[series[float]]. The argument should be of type: series[na];
11:28:30 Error at 17:0 Too much arguments;
11:28:30 Error at 18:0 Variable 'y' was declared with 'array[series[integer]]' type. Cannot assign it expression of type 'void'.

Comment: @MatiasIgnacio ok.  Let's move step by step : did my answer solve the problem you described in yout first question ?

Comment: I replaced it and then those 3 more problems appeared in the code

Comment: @MatiasIgnacio, please proceed step by step :  did my answer solve the problem you described in yout first question ?

Comment: Yes, it did, thank you very much, although those 3 errors appeared later

Comment: @MatiasIgnacio Great ! Can you open a new question with the new code you use and the problem you face ? I will help you